# Getting Keys from SelectOption in a String List

Tags: apex, selectoption

I have a getter method to create a SelectOption. I want to put all the keys in Returned value to a List in another Method.

```
public List<SelectOption> getsortlist() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Parent.Profile.Name','Profile Name')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('sObjectType','sObject'));  
        return options; 
    }
```

and retrieving the values here

```
List<SelectOption>  opt = getsortlist();
List<String>  theList = opt.getValue();
```

Error is

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getValue() from the
>   type List

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why can't you maintain a global list/Map? You may iterate through the List/Map to add SelectOption values and use the same in a different method maybe. You can use List type Custom setting if you're OK with approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a list you need a loop to get all value then you can add them in a list. `getValue()` works for single variable not for a list.

```
List<String>  theList = new List<String>();
for(SelectOption so : getsortlist())
    theList.add(so.getValue());
```

[SelectOption GetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_SelectOption_getValue.htm)

Comment: Worked Perfect!